# React with Redux Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `posts` was not specified in `Posts`. Check the render method of `PostsContainer`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to display a list of posts in a react component using redux,  but I get the following warning:

Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `posts` was not specified in `Posts`. Check the render method of `PostsContainer`.

I have the following code:

The posts container:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getInitalPosts } from 'actions/postsActions'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import _ from 'lodash'
import Posts from 'components/PostApp/Posts'

class PostsContainer extends Component {
  static fetchData({ store }) {
    return store.dispatch(getInitalPosts())
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getInitalPosts()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Posts</h2>
        <Posts posts={this.props.posts} />
        <Link to="/">Back to Home</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return { posts: state.posts }
}

export { PostsContainer }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getInitalPosts })(PostsContainer)
```

and the posts component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { List } from 'immutable'

class Posts extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Posts component
        {  
          this.props.posts
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Posts.propTypes = {

  posts: PropTypes.instanceOf(List).isRequired
  //posts: PropTypes.posts
}

export default Posts
```

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]

Here is the post reducer:

```
import * as ActionType from 'actions/postsActions'
import Immutable from 'immutable'

let defaultState = Immutable.fromJS([])
function postsReducers (state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ActionType.INITIAL_POSTS:
      return Immutable.fromJS(action.response)
      break
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default postsReducers
```

And as far as importing the container it's in the routes index:

```
 8  import Questions from 'containers/Questions'
    9  import Question from 'containers/Question'
   10: import Posts from 'containers/Posts'
   11  
   12  export default function(history) {
   ..
   14      <Router history={history}>
   15        <Route path="/" component={App}>
   16:         <Route path="posts" component={Posts} />
   17          <Route path="questions" component={Questions} />
   18          <Route path="questions/:id" component={Question} />
```

Comment: You should check your state e.g. using redux devtools. Your state seems to be composed with `immutable.js`. If your toplevel instance is a `Map` you will have to use get to receive a property: `state => ({ posts: state.get('posts') })`

Comment: Well Yeah it's an immutable list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you importing `PostsContainer`?

If you're doing it like this:

```
import { PostsContainer } from PostsContainer;
```

You won't be importing the `connect`ed version and therefore won't have the `posts` prop you're trying to use inside `PostsContainer`.

Can you post the importing code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running `getInitialPosts` on `componentDidMount` of `PostsContainer`, the first time it renders it doesn't have any posts yet so the value for `this.props.posts` is `null`. That's what gets passed to `Posts`, breaking your `propTypes` requirement.

You might add an `if` statement inside the `render` method of `PostsContainer` to only render `Posts` if there are posts, otherwise render a loading spinner.

Comment: Well Yeah it's an immutable list. I'm trying to build off from the following boilerplate and the app in the example does not uses the get method just to render spesific items from the list in the component. Here's the link (I've also posted the reducer in the original question): https://github.com/mz026/universal-redux-template

Comment: It's a universal render. I'm trying to render on the server side.